# How to check file existence with python

Tags: python, cmd, python-os

I need to run the desired program in an application I am developing.
I know I can run cmd commands with the code `os.system` in Python's built-in OS module.

But when I run the `start` command with cmd and try to open an application that is not on the computer, windows shows me an ugly pop-up message. To prevent this, I need to scan the files on the computer and find out if the desired program exists before running the "start" command. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the command `where.exe /?`

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
os.path.exists(directory)
```

To check if a file exists in python.
However, it is better to use:

```
os.path.isfile(directory)
```

In this case so that you wont get the error message with the path does not point to a file, but still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know the exact location of the file, I only know its name (Example: pycharm). Is it possible for me to check for file existence this way?

Comment: how are you executing the file without knowing where it is?

Comment: The start command in the command prompt can run some applications (I don't know how). In short, I only have the name of the application.